# Updating list elements by indices

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to add 5 to my specific list indices using list comprehension

**Input**

```
arr=[0,0,0,0,0]
```

**Output**

```
arr=[0,0,5,5,5]
```

I tried

```
[arr[i]+=5 for i in range(2,4)]
```

but it gives an error.

Comment: so whats the efficient way around to do this?

Comment: @Rotten I mean, a list comprehension *can* update another list, but it probably shouldn't

Comment: `for i in range(2,5): a[i] += 5`

Comment: Why not a simple for loop?

Comment: @JaredGoguen Nice, was typing that up was you commented.

Comment: isnt list comprehesion highly effecient compared to loop?

Comment: @WendingPeng I have updated my question.

Comment: @ShashiTunga See my link above and others' comments and answers.

Comment: @ShashiTunga no, it is not "highly efficient compared to a loop", it is *marginally* faster, but it should not be used with side-effects. It is for *creating new lists*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Don't* use list comprehensions for side effects. The purpose of a list comp is to *create* a new list. To that end, I believe you can use `enumerate` + `range` here -

```
l, u = 2, 4
arr = [x + 5 if i in range(l, u + 1) else x for i, x in enumerate(arr)]

print(arr)
[0, 0, 5, 5, 5]
```

In python3, this should be very efficient because `in` checks on `range` objects are `O(1)` time. On python2, it would be faster to perform a boolean check (this is what an `in` check on `range` does in python3) -

```
arr = [x + 5 if l <= i <= u else x for i, x in enumerate(arr)]
```

---

However, keep in mind that a `for` loop would be the most efficient method to use here.

```
for i in range(l, u + 1):
    arr[i] += 5

print(arr)
[0, 0, 5, 5, 5]
```

Because,

1. You only iterate over the indices you need to. Nothing more, nothing less
2. You make changes in place, rather than creating a new `list`

Comment: Answers are getting standards. This is the sort of answers SO expects.

Comment: `x + 5 if lo <= i <= hi else x`... should be faster than `i in range`...

Comment: @f5r5e5d On python2, yes. On python3, it really makes no difference.

Comment: nope, `lo <= i <= hi` is 4x faster on my machine, python 3.6 - both are O(1) though

Comment: @f5r5e5d interesting. It's possibly due to the fact that a `range` object is created each time the evaluation is to be done. Since that is a loop invariant, taking it out of the loop might improve its speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use addition of lists by slicing them here :

```
arr[0:2] + [i+5 for i in arr[2:5]]

[0, 0, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try without for loop something like this:

```
list_1=[0,0,0,0,0]
b=list(range(2,5))
list(map(lambda x,y:list_1.__setitem__(x,list_1[x]+5),b,list_1))
print(list_1)
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Pythonic way to use a list comprehension to replace some indices. In this case, every index except the 2 first ones:

```
>>> arr = [0,0,0,0,0]
>>> arr[2:] = [i + 5 for i in arr[2:]]
>>> arr
[0, 0, 5, 5, 5]
```

Note that `arr` isn't an array, but a list. With [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), the operation becomes easier:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> arr
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> arr[2:] += 5
>>> arr
array([0, 0, 5, 5, 5])
```

It also works if you have a list of indices:

```
>>> arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> arr
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> arr[[2, 3, 4]]
array([0, 0, 0])
>>> arr[[2, 3, 4]] += 5
>>> arr
array([0, 0, 5, 5, 5])
```